# Why target blank is not working in ie 8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Here I am having hyperlink to download the pdf named "sample". `target="_blank"` is working fine in firefox and chrome.. not in Internet Explorer 8. Is there any alternate way to open a new file in IE 8?

```
   <a href="sample.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Note: This is not working in local html's but working fine in servers

Comment: what happens when you click? is sample.pdf in the same folder as the html page?

Comment: I have test_download.html and sample.pdf on my desktop. In test_download.html I have this code: `<a target="_blank" href="sample.pdf">sample.pdf</a>` and it works fine in IE8

Comment: Yes I put sample.pdf in a same page. It is not even responding anything when I click Download hyperlink..

Comment: @HamzaKubba `_blank` has a special meaning, and `_new` is an invalid target name as a [context name **must not** start with a `"_"` character](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.browsing-context-name-def) (the only valid targets that start with `_` are currently: `_blank`, `_self`, `_parent`, or `_top`)

Comment: Hamza Kubba: not working

Comment: No one know the answer???????????